# Android maps v2 maps becomes unresponsive on orientation changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I am using new maps api. its working fine..
But when the device orientation changes.. the map become unresponsive. i mean map doesn't react to the user response.

This, problem doesn't occurs when i embed the map fragment in the layout xml. but occurs only when i am trying to add the mapfragment in the layout container in the Activity's onCreate.

Can anyone tell me the problem.

Here the way i am adding the map

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in Activity's oncreate

```
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.activity_home_fragment_container, mMapFragment,
            "MAP_FRAGMENT");
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: This issue is closed to this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16411783/1258492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this in your layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="35.22"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            map:cameraTargetLat="40.72"
            map:cameraTargetLng="-74.00"
            map:cameraZoom="8" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**And this code:**

```
onCreate{
   setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

private void setUpMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Hide the zoom controls as the button panel will cover it.
        mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
 // Enables/disables zoom gestures (i.e., double tap, pinch & stretch).
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
// Enables/disables scroll gestures (i.e. panning the map).
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
 // Enables/disables the compass (icon in the top left that indicates the orientation of the
        // map).
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        // Add lots of markers to the map.
        addMarkersToMap();

        // Pan to see all markers in view.
        // Cannot zoom to bounds until the map has a size.
        final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1).getView();
        if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi") // We check which build version we are using.
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                            .include(WOODS)
                            .build();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                      mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                      mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
                }
            });
        }
    }

private void addMarkersToMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Uses a colored icon.
        mWoods = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(WOODS)
                .title("Woods")
                .snippet("R. Quatá, 1016, Vila Olimpia - (11) 3849-6868")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    }
```

Comment: Ya!! its work !! my question .. why the above code is showing that problem.

Comment: Another user related an issue with mapfragment also, maybe is a bug in new v2.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if you add `Fragment` in `Activity's` `onCreate()` without checking if `savedInstanceState == null` then you end up with two (or more) `SupportMapFragments` added one on the other and this is causing this effect.