# android maps stop responding after resuming fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

Listed below is my basic code for controlling the maps. I do some really advanced stuff later. Everything seems to work perfect, until `onResume()`.

Here is the layout, you navigate through the app in 1 single activity, with multiple fragments. This `mapFragment` is contained inside of a fragment. This works fine. However when I add another fragment and push this one on the back stack, when i come back to it later, the map is unresponsive.

I tried fixing this by moving my call to `setupMaps();` into the `onResume()`, however this caused `gMaps` to be null when I get it from `gMaps = mapFragment.getMap();` in the `setViews()`.

How should I handle this?

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

        setupMaps();
        return root;
    }

    private void setupMaps()
    {
        gMaps = null;
        fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.flMapContainer, mapFragment).commit();

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        mapFragment.onResume();
        setViews();
    }

    private void setViews()
    {
        gMaps = mapFragment.getMap();
        getData(); // initializes overlays, markers, polygons etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {           
        mapFragment.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: try to call invalidate()

Comment: Hi, I think there might be another issue with the above code. I have a similar situation, and replacing `transaction.add(` with `transaction.replace(` seems to do the trick. I'm still testing it, so i'm not 100% sure this is the right fix, but maybe this hint will help others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you see anything in your logcat? I've had some issues like this before, and I believe it was related to the old map fragment's View not being removed from its parent ViewGroup before creating a new instance of it. This resulted in errors regarding a duplicate fragment.

Try removing all views from your flMapContainer before you create the new instance of the SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Exactly as you said. Thankyou.

Comment: My pleasure! Glad my pain could help ;)

Comment: I battled the same issue for 3 hours and this solution works for me

Answer (score 4):

To implement Scott Stanchfield's solution:
call cleanFrame() when add/replace another fragment.

```
public void cleanFrame(){
FrameLayout FL = (FrameLayout) thisview.findViewById(R.id.myfragmentcontainer);
   FL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled hardware acceleration inside `manifest.xml` and after it everything started to work successfully:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
 ...
</application>
```