# Map in tab becomes frozen after pause & resume

Tags: android

I am using actionbarsherlock to implement a set of tabs. One of the tabs is a fragment containing a MapView. My onCreateView is as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapv);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();

    try
    {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    }
    catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PARIS, 10));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PARIS).title("Paris").snippet("Great city"));

    return view;
}
```

As you can see, the map is originally displayed zoomed in on Paris, which has a Marker on it. Everything is working fine so far. I see the map and can manually drag and zoom the map. If I then press the button on the side of my phone to cause it to pause, then unlock the phone to resume, I can still drag and zoom. BUT if I switch to another tab, then come back to the map tab, I see the map as I left it, but it no longer responds to drag/zoom. It appears frozen. But no errors are being displayed in my log and I can still flip between tabs.

Without any log errors, I don't know how to track down the problem.

**EDIT:** I'm using Maps **v2**

**EDIT:** I've just found a similar sounding situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409783/android-maps-stop-responding-after-resuming-fragment?rq=1). It may well be the answer, but I don't know quite where to place the code from the suggested solution.

**EDIT:** Just in case the critical code was not in my snippet, here's the whole thing...

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.view.View;

public class TestMapFragment extends Fragment implements TabListener
{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static final LatLng PARIS = new LatLng(48.874,2.347);

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapv);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();

        try
        {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PARIS, 10));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PARIS).title("Paris").snippet("Great city"));

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        mFragment = new TestMapFragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * Using a mapview in a fragment requires you to 'route'
     * the lifecycle events of the fragment to the mapview
     */

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if (mMapView != null)
        {
            mMapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mMapView != null)
        {
            mMapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mMapView != null)
        {
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mMapView != null)
        {
            mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory()
    {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (mMapView != null)
        {
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of adding the fragment `ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);` and also attaching it `ft.attach(mFragment);`?

Comment: I confess I've just cut and paste other peoples stuff. I'm new to fragments. If only one of those two lines is required, please tell me which.

Comment: Only one is needed, as I don't know exactly how you've implemented the tabs I would say to keep `ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);`. Anyway check the API Demos samples from the sdk especially the `FragmentTabs`(`$sdk_folder/samples/android-14/src/com/exampleanroid/apis/app`) class to see how to implement the fragment tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This added line container.removeAllViewsInLayout() seems to have done the trick.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    container.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mMapView.displayZoomControls(true)` right after `mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapv)`?

Comment: displayZoomControls is undefined for the type MapView - maybe that's a version 1 vs version 2 issue.

Comment: I found it in the docs here labeled as deprecated but not removed...https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView

Comment: I think you're looking at v1 documentation.

Comment: If you are using V2 then why don't you use MapFragment or SupportMapFragment?

Comment: Because the map must be *inside* a fragment.

Comment: you can put a fragment inside a fragment. Use getChildFragmentManager() on the support library

Comment: Ok, well if I don't get a good answer here, I'll investigate that route.

Comment: did you try googleMap.getUiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);?

Comment: Yes, and setAllGesturesEnabled too. No change :-(

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem 
i have done something like this

Fragment activity which will hold the fragments

Map_main_screen.java

```
public class Map_main_screen extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "TAB one",
            "Second tab GOOGLE MAP", };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.map_new);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);

==========================new_class_GoogleMusicAdapter============================
    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return Map_google_TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position
                    % CONTENT.length]);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
    // =================adapter ends here===============================
}
```

Map_google_TestFragment.java

```
  public final class Map_google_TestFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";
        Typeface tf;

        public static Map_google_TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
    Map_google_TestFragment fragment = new  Map_google_TestFragment();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                builder.append(content).append(" ");
            }
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
            fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

            return fragment;
        }


        private String mContent = "???";
        private int[] mICONS = { 1 };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if ((savedInstanceState != null)
                    && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
                mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v;
            if (mContent.toString().equals("TAB one")) {
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_SECOND_LAYOUT, null);

                          //***************************************
                          // function related to your first fragment 
                          //***************************************

            } else {

                          //***************************************
                          // inflate your Google  map layout here 
                          // function related to your Second fragment 
                          //***************************************
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false); //INFLATE GOOGLE MAP LAYOUT
                     mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapv); 
                    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     mMapView.onResume();

                   try
                   {
                     MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
                    }
                   catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
                    {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PARIS, 10));

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PARIS).title("Paris").snippet("Great city"));

                    return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
        }

    }
```